# How do I make UITableViewCell's ImageView a fixed size ,Texts not aligning properly?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

How do I set imageView's size fixed in tableViewCell so that texts and images aligned properly..

I have tried following things

```
     self.imageView?.frame.size.width = 40.0
     self.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)

     cell.imageView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingNone );
     self.imageView?.autoresizesSubviews = false
     cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
     self.imageView?.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
     cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
     self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can add width and height constraints to imageView in your cell prototype in the storyboard.

Comment: there is no imageview in storyboard ,can you tell me how to do it from uitableviewcell class?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set width or height constraint from code.

```
yourImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let widthContsraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100 // your_value)
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100 // your_value)
yourImageView.addConstraints([widthContsraint, heightConstraint])
```